# Compass moving between 360 and 0 and checking if there is a negative change

Tags: java, if-statement, compass, degrees

I have a compass, that returns degrees between 0-360 and a starting position (degrees) of the initial value of the compass, along with a threshold.

```
degrees = 0-360
initialDegrees = null
threshold = 20
```

I have this check:

```
if(degrees > initialDegrees+threshold || initialDegrees == null) { // this is to start the checking
    foo(); 
    initialDegrees = degrees
}
```

for checking if the degrees have changed positively beyond the threshold (i.e. me moving the compass to the right)

However how do i check if it has been moved in the opposite direction (changed negatively beyond the threshold, i.e. me moving the compass to the left).

```
if(degrees > initialDegrees-thredshold) // this is always true, and doesn't do what i want
```

Is there a way i can do this?
Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should check for `null` first otherwise you can get a NullPointerException.

Comment: My first instinct was "do `degrees < initialDegrees-threshold` instead", but you need to do proper angle arithmetic instead (for example, 350 + 20 = 10, -40 = 320, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `shortestAngle` function. Some math libraries already have it, but you can write your own. Given 2 angles, you need to find the smallest angle (in absolute value), such that the first angle plus this result equals the second angle:

```
public static float shortestAngle(float from, float to) {
    float difference = to - from; //step 1: do flat difference
    difference %= 360; //step 2: do module 360 to normalize to (-360, 360) range
    if(difference < 0) {
        difference += 360; //step3: normalize to [0, 360) range
    }
    if(difference > 180) {
        difference -= 360; //step 4: normalize to (-180, 180] range
    }
    return difference;
}
```

After that you just compare if the shortest angle is greater than threshold, or lower than negative threshold.

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly in my case. However, do you mind explaining your if statements in greater detail, as I'm not entirely sure i understand what step 3 and 4 do.

Comment: If the difference is -200 for some reason, you want it to be 160 instead, since it is the "same" angle, but 160 is less rotation than -200. Same with high values like 300 being converted to -60 by the step 4.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the difference.

```
int delta = degrees - initialDegrees;
if (delta > 180)
    delta -= 360; // its a negative move.
if (delta < -180)
    delra += 360; // actually positive.
if (Math.abs(delta) > threshold)
    // meaningful move.
```

You can use math to avoid the `if` statements

```
delta = (delta + 360 + 180) % 360 - 180; // all values between -180 and 179.
```

or

```
delta = (delta + 360 + 179) % 360 - 179; // all values between -179 and 180.
```

Comment: Don't forget the case where `delta < 0`.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus < 0 is fine but need for check for < -180